# Generics- am I missing something or what is the point?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code:

```
public class AClass<X extends AnInterface> implements AnotherInterface {

    public AClass(X x){
    }

}
```

Why would I use `X` as the constructor parameter type, when I could just replace this with `AnInterface`?? Surely they mean the same thing, anything which is a subtype of `AnInterface`?

I am trying to keep all my parameter types as generic and only mention Interface names in the generic parametric declarations eg "X extends AnInterface" but running into problems because it is saying the value I pass in, which is of type AnInterface, is not equal to type X.

EDITED:

```
public void<X extends AnInterface> myMethod(){


    AnInterface b = new ADiffClass();
    AnotherInterface a = new AClass(b);
}

public class ADiffClass<X extends AnInterface> implements AnInterface {

    public ADiffClass(){
    }

}
```

This is where I am having problems, I get a compile error saying that the type of b is AnInterface and the type required in the constructor of AClass is X.

Comment: Please show the code causing the compilation error, and explain what you want it to do.

Comment: The above doesn't compile, but not for the reason you state. It should be `public <X extends AnInterface> void  myMethod()`. Once fixed, it compiles (with raw type warnings)

Comment: yup and to remove those I insert <X> before the argument brackets = new AClass<X>(b) and there is nothing wrong with using generics like this?

Comment: That makes the code not compile. You shouldn't be trying to just remove warnings by adding random generics arguments everywhere. You need to understand what you're doing.

Comment: They're not random? In the method X extends AnInterface. In class AClass the generics state X extends AnInterface?

Comment: Just because it makes the warning disappear doesn't meanit's correct. I get the feeling that you designed many generic types without knowing why and how, and that you're now trying to use them without warnings, but still without knowing why.

Comment: I have an attribute in my class, I have extracted this type out, replaced it with a generic placeholder and then incorporated the type into the parametric declaration of the class. The same type is sometimes used as parameters for constructors/methods (as my example above).... im using it as a placeholder- because thats what it is? It just means "wherever you see X, this can be any subtype of AnInterface" ?

Comment: No, it's not what it means. It means: wherever you see X it will be of a specific type which implements AnInterface, and this type will be defined when the variable is declared. And that doesn't explain why you need to make this attribute generic, and why you chose to make it generic.

Comment: Well my original question was, what is the point of generics when I can declare the constructor type as the Interface type? As I see it, they would achieve the same thing? If I removed all the generics from my example above, I could replace them with Interface "types".

Comment: Read my answer again. If you don't need to restrict the type of AClass to a specific subtype of AnInterface, there is no point in making AClass generic. Why you made AClass generic without understanding what the goal is is still a mystery to me.

Comment: I need to limit it because in the actual code X will call methods that only subtypes of that interface will possess?? The interface specifies the "contract". I dont see much point in using generics if you arent going to limit them- as you cant be assured what methods are provided for said types?

Comment: Let's stop this discussion. It won't lead to anything, as all I know about your code is AClass, AnInterface and AnotherInterface, which doesn't say anything about what you actually want to do.

Comment: I have asked why should I use generics instead of relying on dynamic binding several times now and you've avoided answering it each time ad tell me I dont know why I am using generics- withotu saying why someone should use generics. If I am wrong please enlighten me

Comment: I've answered that question in my answer, and Francisco Spaeth has answered the same thing: it allows your "container" class to be more restrictive about the type of objects it holds. If you don't need that, then don't make the type generic. I already said that in one of my comments above as well. Your explanation "X will call methods that only subtypes of that interface will possess" doesn't make any sense. X is a generic type. A generic type can't call any method. If you want a List to hold Strings, or Integers only, you make it generic. If you want it to hold any kind of Object, you don't.

Comment: So if I am not writing a container class, but say I have a composite relationship- does this mean I shouldn't use generics? (Even if the composite attribute can be one of many different subtypes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you declare a variable like this:

```
private AClass<Foo> a;
```

the following will be valid:

```
 a = new AClass<Foo>(new Foo());
```

but the following wwon't:

```
 a = new AClass<Foo>(new Bar());
```

(assuming `Foo` and `Bar` are two implementations of `AnInterface`).

That's the point of generics in that case: restrict the type to a specific type that implements (or extends) AnInterface.

Comment: This doesn't really answer *why* you would want to use generics in this case. He's asking why you couldn't just accept an interface in the constructor and use: `new AClass(new Foo());` and `new AClass(new Bar());` (ie: what's the benefit of using generics here?).

Comment: Im also curious if you would declare (in your example) a of type P if <P extends AnInterface> was the parametric declaration at the class/method level?

Comment: @Ocelot20: The benefit of using generics is that it allows declaring a variable accepting a specific subclass of AnInterface only. Whether that's a good idea or not depends on what the type is for, where it's used and how, and what the rest of the class looks like. But I don't have any idea of that. The OP only knows. Of course, if the class only has a constructor and nothing else, generics don't add any value, but the class itself doesn't serve any purpose in this case.

Comment: @JBNizet My point is that isnt that what declaring the variable using the interface name does also? In your example I could declare a of type AnInterface?

Comment: Let's take a more meaningful example. A Painter<Color> is a class that is able to paint with the given color. It's not a Color. A List<String> is a List holding String instances. It's not a String. You're confusing the type of the class with the type of its generic parameter.

Comment: @JBNizet I have edited to include my problem in the original question JB Nizet.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you have this situation:

```
public class AClass<X extends AnInterface>{

    public AClass(X x){
        ...
    }

    public X getIt() {
        ...
    }

}
```

The one who is creating the object will have an interface accordingly to it, in this situation it would be useful.

For instance:

```
// supposing DefaultAnInstance is an implementation of AnInstance interface
DefaultAnInterface obj = new DefaultAnInterface();
AClass<DefaultAnInterface> instance = new AClass<DefaultAnInterface>(obj);
...
// for the user getIt will return an objecct of type DefaultAnInterface
DefaultAnInterface obj = instance.getIt(); // there is no need to cast it to DefaultAnInterface
```

Comment: I have the situation you have described. However, the value I pass into the constructor is of type AnInterface and the constructor is saying its not of type X (even though X extends AnInterface)

Comment: this is correct, your class will handle it as `AnInterface` type, but for the user it will be of type he defined. Of course the type needs to extend `AnInterface`. I just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to extend an interface? Do you mean to implement it? I think the problem is that you are using a class where you should be using an interface. If you want to be able to pass in something of multiple classes, that is precisely what an interface is for.

Comment: I want X to be of the type of any subtypes of the Interface?

Comment: He's not extending the interface.  The "extends" syntax in generics applies to both subclassing and interface implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Given your AClass, you may want it to be less general than your average generic - it can't handle any type, like a generic such as LinkedList can, but you want it to be able to handle a lot of classes.

For example, let's say you've got a class SelfSortingList, which is generic.  All of its objects need to be comparable for it to be sortable.  But you don't want to allow Widgets and Levers, which both implement Comparable, to be in the same list; that wouldn't make sense, and their particular implementations of Comparable probably reflect that.

So what you do is you say, "I want my SelfSortingList to be able to hold Objects of the same type, but they must be comparable."  That's why you have both a type parameter (X) and a limitation on what X can be (extends Comparable) in the class header SelfSortingList.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you couldn't.  However, this would probably break the rest of your generic class:

```
public class AClass<X extends AnInterface> {
    private X anInterface;
    public AClass(AnInterface anInterface) {
       // Not legal.  You'd have to narrow cast to X
       this.anInterface = anInterface;
    }
}
```

So, you could always change the declaration of "anInterface" to AnInterface instead of X.  However, generics are not giving you anything, since you're not referring to X anymore

```
public class AClass<X extends AnInterface> {
    private AnInterface anInterface;
    public AClass(AnInterface anInterface) {
       // Not legal.  You'd have to narrow cast to X
       this.anInterface = anInterface;
    }
}
```

Where's the use of X? You'd be inserting a generic parameter which isn't used.

Then there's the also the constructor typesafety issues some mentioned in another answer.

And these two constructors DO NOT MEAN THE SAME THING:

```
public AClass(AnInterface anInterface) { ... }
public AClass(X anInterface) { ... }
```

The first means you can have ANY class that is assignment compatible with AnInterface (ie. implements or extends it).  The second means that you can have any class which is assignment compatible with the supplied generic parameter, which may be MORE SPECIFIC than just AnInterface.  Someone used this example above:

```
public class Int1 implements AnInterface { ... }
public class Int2 implements AnInterface { ... }
public class Int3 extends Int1 { ... }
```

So if you have:

```
AClass<Int1>  --> it could accept either Int1 or Int3, but not Int2 in the constructor
AClass<Int2>  --> it could accept only Int2 in the constructor
```